# react native app not install on android virtual device

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

In my case react native application was built successfully without any error but it can't open. what is the reason behind it please explain to me and help me to solve this problem.

Comment: you mean metro bundler does not open it automatically and you have to open it manually?

Comment: can you help me to solve this problem? what can I do to solve this problem I don't know what to do I am new in react native please help me.

Comment: you need to first elaborate your issue properly, is it android issue or ios? is it that your app does not open automatically and you have to open it manually? whats the problem?

Comment: I face the problem in android. whenever I run the command npx react-native run-android I didn't get any error but while installing the app the app is not opening.

Comment: This happens when you android bundle id is different from android package id. 
you will have to manually open the app.